# vb6 - populate treeview

Tags: vb6, treeview

I need to populate treeview with folders name i got from few paths. Example, I have this few paths :
C:\admin\tester1\project\item1\abc, 
C:\admin\tester1\project\item2\abc,
C:\admin\tester1\project\item1\def,
C:\admin\tester1\project3\item2\ghi

Can you all provide me some idea or examples on how to put the paths into treeview?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the root node then add each level as a child of the root node or it's parent.

```
' Add Node objects.
Dim nodX As Node  ' Declare Node variable.
' First node with 'Root' as text.
Set nodX = TreeView1.Nodes.Add(, , "r", "Root")

' This next node is a child of Node 1 ("r").
Set nodX = TreeView1.Nodes.Add("r", tvwChild, "child1", "Child")

' This next node is a child of Node 2 ("child").
Set nodX = TreeView1.Nodes.Add("child1", tvwChild, "child2", "Child 2")
```

This code will ad a root node called "Root" then a child node called "Child" and then a child to that child node called "Child 2".  This is the best drawing I can fake in here :-)

Root
|-Child
|        |-Child 2

Comment: thanks. However, after splitting each path into several folders, I would not know which parent it belongs to. Besides, how can I check whether does the root already exist or not

Answer (score 0):

Add a `TreeView` control on a form and try this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
    pvAddPath TreeView1, "C:\admin\tester1\project\item1\abc"
    pvAddPath TreeView1, "C:\admin\tester1\project\item2\abc"
    pvAddPath TreeView1, "C:\admin\tester1\project\item1\def"
    pvAddPath TreeView1, "C:\admin\tester1\project3\item2\ghi"
End Sub

Private Sub pvAddPath(oCtl As TreeView, ByVal sPath As String)
    Dim lNext           As Long
    Dim lStart          As Long

    If oCtl.Nodes.Count = 0 Then
        oCtl.Indentation = 0
    End If
    Do While lStart < Len(sPath)
        lNext = InStr(lStart + 1, sPath, "\")
        If lNext = 0 Then
            lNext = Len(sPath) + 1
        End If
        On Error Resume Next
        If lStart = 0 Then
            oCtl.Nodes.Add(, , Left$(sPath, lNext), Left$(sPath, lNext)).Expanded = True
        Else
            oCtl.Nodes.Add(Left$(sPath, lStart), tvwChild, Left$(sPath, lNext), Mid$(sPath, lStart + 1, lNext - lStart - 1)).Expanded = True
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        lStart = lNext
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out MSDN topic: [Using the TreeView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733703%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)